# Google Sheets: Making an Arrrayformula for Countif Function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm currently upgrading my sheets for an MTB program. I'm changing all my formulas to arrayformula so as to avoid anyone being left out when I forgot to drag the formula.

All that's left is the formula in cell J3.

Here's the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cRINly3eiB5DXvug4AxyqmZtp7nU8rVo2lR58WC1trQ/edit#gid=1148057086) to the spreadsheet.

The formula is to count each plate numbers and if it matches with F2, return its latest time.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try:

```
=BYROW(C3:C,LAMBDA(cx,IF(cx="",,IF(COUNTIF(G:G,cx)=F2,IFNA(VLOOKUP(cx,SORT(G:H,2,),2,)),"DNF"))))
```